# Activity dialog themed

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am creating an Android widget.  My widget has a View that when clicked opens an `Activity` that's look like an `Dialog`.

I have updated `AndroidManifest.xml` to style this activity like a dialog.

```
<activity 
    android:name=".Widget.Widget_OeffneDialog" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

That runs fantastic.

Now I open the app from this Widget and click on the home button (the app is now in the background) and then click on the wdget the Dialog shows - but the rest of the app shows behind the dialog.

Like here:
[image]

I do not want to see the previous activity below the dialog activity - how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are launching the Widget_OeffneDialog activity from the launcher, Android is simply resuming the instance that is currently in the background - along with whatever backstack and history it contains.

Try forcing your widget to launch a new instance of the activity instead.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Theme.Translucent for that. The Translucent theme won't darken the App/view in the background.
Note that the Translucent theme doesn't use animations, so you might want to change that. Here's the theme XML from the Android source:

```
 <style name="Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <!-- Note that we use the base animation style here (that is no
         animations) because we really have no idea how this kind of
         activity will be used. -->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

Comment: sorry but i think that isnt what i want. This solution make the Background transparent. But i if click on the back-button the app shows the "Main"-Activity. The only thing I want is a Dialog like here: http://x.co/tMom